# Extracting Uncommon values from 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Given two data frames containing dates:

```
d1
#        dates
#    2016-08-01
#    2016-08-02
#    2016-08-03
#    2016-08-04

d2
#        dates
#    2016-08-02
#    2016-08-03
#    2016-08-04
#    2016-08-05
#    2016-08-06
```

How do I create a 3rd dataframe that would have the not-common values?

```
d3
#        dates
#    2016-08-01
#    2016-08-05
#    2016-08-06
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(17014, 17015, 17016, 17017 ), 
class = "Date")), .Names = "dates", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class =  
"data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(17015, 17016, 17017, 17018, 
17019), class = "Date")), .Names = "dates", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class 
= "data.frame")
```

Comment: How's `rbind(dplyr::anti_join(df1,df2), dplyr::anti_join(df2,df1))`?

Comment: Why `rbind`? Can you just `dplyr::anti_join(df1, df2, by = "dates")`? (Edit: this is not right, it's for those in x not in y.)

Comment: @r2evans, I was under the impression that anti_join returns all rows from x where there are not matching values in y. Not vice-versa. I can double-check.

Comment: I misread, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Abdou This pops up an error for date fields.`Error in UseMethod("anti_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "Date"`

Comment: This is what I am working with: `df1 <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(17014, 17015, 17016, 17017
), class = "Date")), .Names = "dates", row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")` and `df2 <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(17015, 17016, 17017, 17018, 
17019), class = "Date")), .Names = "dates", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")`. I am not really sure what your actual data is like but that should work with your sample dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two vectors `x` and `y`, elements that are not shared are

```
c(x[!(x %in% y)], y[!(y %in% x)])
```

If you work with data frames, provided that your `dates` column is "character" or "Date" instead of "factor", you can do

```
rbind(subset(df1, !(df1$dates %in% df2$dates)),
      subset(df2, !(df2$dates %in% df1$dates)))
```

---

**Simple vector example**

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 3:8
c(x[!(x %in% y)], y[!(y %in% x)])
# [1] 1 2 6 7 8
```

**Vector of "Date"**

```
x <- seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), length = 5, by = 1)
y <- seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-03"), length = 5, by = 1)
c(x[!(x %in% y)], y[!(y %in% x)])
# [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-06" "2016-01-07"
```

---

**Example data frame in your question**

```
rbind(subset(df1, !(df1$dates %in% df2$dates)),
      subset(df2, !(df2$dates %in% df1$dates)))

#       dates
#1 2016-08-01
#4 2016-08-05
#5 2016-08-06
```

Comment: The class of both the dates field is "Date" only. However using that `rbind` code returns a 2-row list with numbers instead of dates. It also gives a warning message `number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`. Anything I missed?

Comment: @ZheyuanAli This gives me `structure(16832, class = "Date")` and `structure(16804, class = "Date")`

Comment: @ZheyuanAli I changed it to vectors and tried the solution and it worked. I'll try the subset solution as well.

Comment: @ZheyuanAli, I didn't try the `setdiff` function. Should explore that one.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use a join as others have shown. Personally I like using `?setops` in base R. Something like this:

```
# if they are just character/factor variables
setdiff(d1$dates, d2$dates)
# if they are date variables
setdiff(as.character(d1$dates), as.character(d2$dates)) 
# then convert back to as.Date(setdiff(...))
```

Applying this, you could filter the data.frame based on the result, or like @ZheyuanLi has indirectly identified, use matching to exclude:

```
# If they are date variables
d2[!as.character(d2$dates) %in% as.character(d1$dates),]
# If they are character/factor variables
d2[!d2$dates %in% d1$dates,]
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to eventually use `rbind`? `setdiff` works from left to right, I think.

Comment: See `?setops` for more details. No `rbind` required here at all. Really we're just comparing two vectors. The data.frame is just a matter of subsetting/filtering.